# How to count total number of items being passed through a loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to see what the best way to count the total number of items being passed through a loop would be.

Currently, I am able to get it to give me a total number. however, it is undefined, and I need to be able to use this number to do another calculation.

CURRENT CODE

```
 //loop to go match selection and create a new array
    for (i = 0; i < origData.length; i++) {
        if (origData[i][3] == selection) {
            // only data that meets the selection criteria goes into newData array
            let sort = newData.push(origData[i]);

            //Count total numbers in loop
            let count = sort.length;

            //Result = count / by total (pre determined number)
            let result = count / 89
            console.log(result);
        } //end if
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.push` returns the number of elements in the array - _not_ a new array. So `sort.length` has no meaning here. change `sort.length` to `newData.length`

Comment: The code that uses the count should probably be after the loop is done.

Comment: or just just use `sort` which is the length of the array.

Comment: [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) does not return the array with the new elements but the _length_ of the array. When you try to compute the `length` of this you get `Undefined`